# $lookup : return model if reference field is not empty

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have `College` model which has `ref :"University"`. each college has 1 university when the college is created.

so I'm trying to get all the colleges where the `uuid` of the university matches the request query.

So i tried the following :

```
  const myAggregate = College.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        language: req.query.language,
        display_language: req.query.display_language
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'unis', // UNIVERSITY COLLECTION
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $eq: ["$uuid", req.query.id]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        as: 'univ',
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: { createdAt: -1 },
    },
  ])
```

so the above code when the query is provided and it does not equal the university UUID , it fetches all the colleges but the `univ` array is empty of each college.

is it possible to only show the colleges when the `uuid` equals the query id and not show an empty array of `univ` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do unwind to remove empty ones.

Doc reference:https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

```
 const myAggregate = College.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        language: req.query.language,
        display_language: req.query.display_language
      }
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'unis', // UNIVERSITY COLLECTION
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $eq: ["$uuid", req.query.id]
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        as: 'univ',
      },
    },
   {"$unwind":{
 path: '$univ',
preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false}},
    {
      $sort: { createdAt: -1 },
    },
  ])
```